# Django next page in pagination on form submission

Tags: django

```
def listing(request):

    contact_list = Question.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 1) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
```

Let's say in each page I have a form, and when the form submitted I need to go to the next page.

I first tried to add a hidden field in the form, and manually calculate the next page, and put into HTTPResponseRedirect, but then I get an empty object error for the last page  because of the following:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">
```

*That page contains no results*

```
{% for contact in contacts %}
{# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
{{ contact.question_text|upper }}<br>
...


<form action="{% url 'listing' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in contact.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if contacts.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if contacts.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        <a href="?page={{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

So what should be my strategy? Do I need to create a seperate view for form action, or should I use **listing** as form action and check wheter it is a GET/POST method, I am kind of lost here.

Comment: why do loose the pagination after redirecting? If you redirect to the url with the correct `?page=...` then this should just work. Maybe show all the code you've written, because right now there's no form and no POST.

Comment: @dirkgroten updated the question with the problem, error happens only on the last page.

Comment: check `contacts.has_next` and assign the value depending on that.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank your suggestion finally solved. It works, but do you think passing it like this in a hidden way a good coding practice?

Comment: yes, sure, most login forms do it this way in order to ensure the user ends up where they came from when logging in. There's nothing secret about it and nothing 'hackable' about it either. If a user tampers the form, he'll just get to another page than the one intended, but there's usually no side effect.